# How to pan around the shader editor on a mac?

Tags: node-editor, interface, navigation

I just opened Blender and I opened the shader editor for the first time. I wanted to read the properties of the node which is there, but I can not since it falls outside the view. I hold my middle mouse button to pan, but that made it only zoom in/out.

How can I pan my view in the shader editor?

Comment: Shift-MMB-Drag should track you in the node editors ..  Home to centre all, Numpad ' . ' to centre on selected?

Comment: Shift-MMB does not do anything. The other alternatives I can not try since I work on a Macbook. Double finger tracking in the trackpad doesn't work neither.

Comment: OK, sorry .. I can only look up ' Blender Navigate Mac ', as you could, but no Mac here to check it out. Maybe put that it's a Macbook in your Q. title.

Comment: If you have a Macbook, you can also scroll around with 2 fingers on the trackpad. You can also pinch to zoom in and out.

Comment: On my mac, I can just scroll with two fingers to pan in the shader editor.

Comment: The suggested panning with two fingers does not work in my Blender. I have done a factory reset and that fixed the problem. The problem had to do with the key bindings for panning within the 2D view did not exist. I must have removed it in the past, not knowing what I was doing ‍♂️